# Чтение и запись информации в бинарный файл

Tags: c++, структуры, файловый-ввод-вывод

Мне необходимо выполнить задание:

Тема: "Бинарные файлы. Файл из структур"

Для каждого из вариантов задания необходимо разработать
следующие функции:
1. Создание файла.
2. Добавление элемента в конец файла.
3. Вывод содержимого файла на экран.
4. Удаление элемента из файла:
- элемента с заданным номером;
- элемента с заданным ключом.
5. Упорядочивание элементов в файле по выбранному
признаку. Методы сортировки:
1. пузырьком;
2. перемешиванием;
3. вставками;
4. подсчетом;
5. слиянием;
6. выбором;
7. Шелла;

6. «Владелец автомобиля»:
   фамилия; имя; отчество; номер телефона; домашний адрес (почтовый индекс,страна, область, район,
   город, улица, дом, квартира) марка автомобиля; номер автомобиля; номер техпаспорта.

Пытаюсь найти информацию на данную тему. Насколько я понял, бинарный файл отличается от обычного текстового файла тем, что в бинарном вместо значения переменной записывается бинарный код переменной. Мне довелось делать задание с текстовым файлом и структурой до этого. По сути, я должен сделать то же самое, что и с обычным файлом, только записывать не значения, а бинарные коды. При выполнении функции я думаю следует проводить действия над переменными, как и обычно, просто после выполнения записывать результат в файл в виде кода и затем выводить на экран содержимое файла. Но что-то мне кажется, что это как-то странно. И не могу понять, прав я или нет. Что вы думаете на этот счёт?

На эту тему свежей информации не нашёл. Поэтому пришлось довольствоваться вот этим:

```
#include <iostream> //Для работы с клавиатурой
#include <fstream> //Для работы с файловыми потоками
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int y = 0; //Y будем записывать в файл
    int x = 0; //X будем считывать из файла

    cout << "Y = "; cin >> y; //Вводим число, которое нужно сохранить в файл
    ofstream out("File.txt",ios::binary|ios::out); //Открываем файл в двоичном режиме для записи
    out.write((char*)&y, sizeof y); //Записываем в файл число y
    out.close(); //Закрываем файл

    cout << "x = " << x << endl; //Показываем X до его изменений

    ifstream in("File.txt",ios::binary|ios::in); //Открываем файл в двоичном режиме только для чтения
    in.read((char*)&x, sizeof x); //Читаем оттуда информацию и запоминаем её в X
    in.close(); //Закрываем файл

    cout << "x = " << x << endl; //Показываем X после изменения
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Это из статьи 2012 года. Я вставил этот код в Visual Studio 2019.

После запуска программы ввёл число 5 для переменной y.

В файле получил вертикальную черту и три треугольника с вопросительным знаком.

В чём же проблема?

Comment: `В файле получил вертикальную черту и три треугольника с вопросительным знаком.` проблемы тут нет, бинарная запись же. int размером 4 байта, вот вы и получили 4 символа. Редактор то показывает содержимое файла в текстовом представлении

Comment: @IR42 понятно, я просто думал, что треугольников быть не может, спасибо :)